# IntelliJ external jar relative path

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm just trying out IntelliJ IDE and I want to add an external jar to my java project.

I have already figured out how to add external jars to my project in `ProjectSettings -> Modules -> Dependencies`. But the path is always absolute. I haven't found a way to **make the path relative** to the project folder (my lib folder is inside my project folder).

e.g. I don't want this
`C:\Users\AUser\IdeaProjects\AProject\lib\alibrary.jar`

Instead I want this. `...\AProject\lib\alibrary.jar`

In Netbeans this was possible by just checking a checkbox.
Is there something similar in IntelliJ?

If not, how do you deal with the situation when someone else is trying to open up your project? Does he need to edit all library paths?

Comment: Have you tried entering the path using `$MODULE_DIR` maybe?

Comment: In the example above I replaced 'AProject' with '$MODULE_DIR' and now it gives me an error 'specified path cannot be found'

Comment: `$MODULE_DIR` will be the directory of the IntelliJ Module - so probably try `$MODULE_DIR/../../AProject/lib/alibrary.jar` (or what your relative path will be)

Comment: No, it's much easier than that.  Go into Project Settings, click Libraries, and mark the directory with the JARs (e.g. /lib) as a JAR directory.  Every library you add to it will be in the CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 1):

I observed everything in `.\lib\` are always automatically re-mapped correctly when the project is moved or when I open a shared project.