# IntelliJ add external jar as dependency from relative path

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Reviving this question: [IntelliJ external jar relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266983/intellij-external-jar-relative-path)
because the answers were not very helpful to me.

> I'm just trying out IntelliJ IDE and I want to add an external jar to my java project.
>
> I have already figured out how to add external jars to my project in
> ProjectSettings -> Modules -> Dependencies. But the path is always
> absolute. I haven't found a way to make the path relative to the
> project folder (my lib folder is inside my project folder).
>
> e.g. I don't want this
> C:\Users\AUser\IdeaProjects\AProject\lib\alibrary.jar
>
> Instead I want this. ...\AProject\lib\alibrary.jar
>
> In Netbeans this was possible by just checking a checkbox. Is there
> something similar in IntelliJ?
>
> If not, how do you deal with the situation when someone else is trying
> to open up your project? Does he need to edit all library paths?

What I want is to be able to add dependencies from a relative path so that my, uh, "Microservice" I guess, will work in tandem with the rest of the project when moved to a different computer, or CI and such. No absolute paths whatsoever.

The responses in the question mention the variable `$MODULE_DIR`. I've found https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/absolute-path-variables.html which has mention of a variable `$MODULE_IML_DIR`. Neither worked for me.

> $MODULE_DIR will be the directory of the IntelliJ Module - so probably try $MODULE_DIR/../../AProject/lib/alibrary.jar (or what your relative path will be)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the library is inside the project root, the path will be stored relatively using the placeholder.

In the library `.xml` file or in the project `.iml` file you'll see something like this:

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="log4j-1.2.17">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</component>
```

Comment: I assume it is also possible to go back from the project root? like `$PROJECT_DIR$/../myJAR.jar` for example?

Comment: I have checked, it seems no matter where the library is stored on my computer be it inside the project root or way outside, it will be stored relatively.